# What is the significance of the value of the limit on the roughness attribute of the Oren Nayar shader?

Tags: materials, shaders

In exploring the settings of the Oren Nayar shader in the Blender internal rendering engine, I find that there is an upper limit of 3.14 for roughness.

Is this the constant *Pi*?

Why is this the upper limit?

How does this upper limit affect the shader?

[NOTE: if the Wikipedia article *[Oren Nayar reflectance model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oren%E2%80%93Nayar_reflectance_model)* includes an explanation that answers these questions, I don't find it. Also note that the current manual does not include any information that there *is* an upper limit.]

Comment: Digging in the source, I found these two: [line where the limit is defined](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_material.c;b1a7fc2c51f7c05babce6b99a1c47572906e253c$1031) and [line where roughness is included in the calculation](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/render/intern/source/shadeoutput.c;b1a7fc2c51f7c05babce6b99a1c47572906e253c$811). The limit seems arbitrary for me, but I don't know anything about this topic.